# Load a function which is out of scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which loads a file at the top of itself containing most of my JQuery functions.

So within the file is e.g.:

```
$().ready(function() {
  function foo(){
    doSomething;
  }
}
```

Now, at the end of that particular page I want to use one of the functions in the file loaded previously.

When I call `foo();` it says `foo is not defined` which I get, my question is can I call that function? And if so how?

I also tried:

```
window.onload = function(e){
  foo();
}
```

but same error

Comment: If the file loaded previously has `foo` declared - it should be accessible.

Comment: You'd have to make `foo` part of some global namespace. Or look into modules, and Browserify, it'll save you some time in the long run.

Comment: You may be trying to call the function before the `.ready` is fired

Comment: How can I declare it globally?

Comment: Something like this: `var utils = {}; $().ready(function(){utils.foo = function(){}})`

Comment: If you need to call `foo` _outside_ of the `$().ready` handler you're probably doing it wrong...

Comment: @DarrenSweeney the question you should ask is _why do I need to access it globally_?   What is `foo` doing that means it needs to be invoked before `$().ready` ?

Comment: Alternatively, if it _does_ need to be global, why hide it inside `$().ready` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are declaring the function inside the scope of the anaonymous functions passed to the ready jQuery method.

```
$().ready(function() {
  function foo(){
    doSomething;
  }
// foo can only be accessed on this scope.
});
```

You can just expose the function to the window scope using the window variable.

```
$().ready(function() {
  window.foo = function foo(){
    doSomething;
  }
// foo can be accessed on this scope and on the gloabl app scope.
});
```

Comment: Excellent thanks, this a new way of declaring out of scope to me and works perfectly.

Comment: but offers _no advantage whatsoever_ over just declaring `foo` globally.  It also suffers the disadvantage of `window.foo` not being defined until after `$().ready`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But that is an answer for his question. Really I don't know why he need that behaviour but is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Declare it in global scope.

```
var foofn;
$().ready(function() {
  foofn = function(){
    doSomething;
  }
})
```

Comment: or - _just move the whole definition outside_ !!

Comment: I agree, was just trying to teach the asker how this **can** be pulled of, not discussing if it is the right approach (I agree it is not in most cases).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to define `foo` where it is globally accessible. Instead of `function foo(){}` try `window.foo = function(){}`.

A slightly less sloppy approach than sticking a bunch of properties on the `window` object would be to define one global object where you put things, e.g.

```
var myApp = {};

$(document).ready(){
    myApp.foo = function(){ doSomething; }
}
```

This way, scripts that execute later on the same page will have access to `myApp.foo`.

Comment: It's not scripts "later on the same page", it's scripts called _after the DOM ready event_.  Anything called in between will fail because `myApp.foo` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

If (and that's a big if) `foo` needs to be called in global scope, then simply declare it in global scope - there's no point hiding it away as an inner function of `$().ready` if that's not where it's going to be used.

If you want to avoid global pollution, wrap the whole thing in an *Immediately Invoked Function Expression*:

```
(function() {

    // called when all resources are loaded
    window.onload = function foo() {
        ...
    }; 

    // called when the DOM is ready
    $().ready(function() {
        ...
    });

})();   // invoke now
```